# How should I approach this double angle problem?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin a=-\frac{3}{5},\quad\quad \pi<a<3\pi/2$$
$$\cos b=\frac{12}{13}, \quad\quad3\pi/2<b<2\pi$$

a)$\sin(a+b)$

b)$\cos(a+b)$

c)$\sin(a-b)$

d)$\tan(a+b)$

e)$\sin(2a)$

f)$\cos(2b)$

g)$\sin (b/2)$

h)$\cos (a/2)$
I know that you have to divide the $\pi<a<3\pi/2$ by two and that will give you the $a/2$. I just need to understand what to do afterward. Got this on a test tomorrow so any help would be appreciated. Also if you recommend any good websites where I can practice similar problems or videos on these types of questions that would help as well.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! We use something called MathJax to make our equations and maths come out nicer, here's a great quick guide to it: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You need to find $\cos a$ and $\sin b$ first, and here is where you use $\pi<a<\frac{3}{2}\pi$ and $\frac{3}{2}\pi<b<2\pi$, namely $$\cos a=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2a}$$and the sign depends on where $a$ is in $[0,2\pi]$ (in particular, in the interval $[\pi,\frac{3}{2}\pi]$ the cosine is negative, so $\cos a=-\sqrt{1-\sin^2a}$). Similarly you find $\sin b$, and then you can find $\sin(a+b),\cos(a+b)$ and all the others using trigonometric formulas.

Comment: [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) will help.

Comment: @Alessandro I found both cos a and sin b so do i now just plug them in for the A-H problems?

Comment: Now you use the correct formulas (from the link given in the comments) to write $\sin(a+b)$, as well as the other values you want to find, as functions of $\cos$ and $\sin$ of $a,b$. In (g) you'll have to mind the sign